# Post thumbnail outside the loop

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to get the post thumbnail in the sidebar which is in essence outside the loop.
For some reason it seems impossible!!!
I have tried all kinds of ways.
Here is the wirking code: (I have edited the code now that I found it)

```
global $wp_query;
$post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;

if (has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ):
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
    $imazz = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium',true);
    $image_url = $imazz[0];
    $image_url = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" alt="'.the_title().'" />';
else :
    php $image_url = '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo-pic-inv.jpg" width="500" height="333" alt="'.__("Δημοσιεύσεις","44db").'" />';
endif;
```

I have also tried using the following code:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); // using the post id
```

and that

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id); // using the fetched post id
```

any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have edited the code and the initial part is correct.

Comment: Do you want to display a Post Thumbnail in the sidebar of a Single Blog Post, or of an archive index page?

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
global $post;


if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
//    
      get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); 
//

}
```

Comment: I also like [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) template tag, more explicit and harder to make mistake with globals.

Comment: But this is outside the loop, so `get_the_id()` wouldn't be too handy here.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you're not inside a loop when you're in the sidebar.  By the time you hit the sidebar your loop has finished, so even getting  $wp_query->post->ID won't work.

Try doing:

```
rewind_posts();
the_post();
```

to reset the loop and then get the first entry loaded up, before the code you included.

If you wanted to be a bit better then you can do:

```
rewind_posts();
if (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Hope that helps